# The method abc(long) is undefined for the type ABC

Tags: java, dependencies

I am having this issue where Project B has dependency on Project A.
Project A has this interface which has the below method structure -

```
public XYZ retrieveMPFactorNum(long a)
            throws SQLException;
```

The interface is implemented by a class and method structure is same as above.

Also the class in Project B are using several other methods from that interface of Project A but only my newly added method is causing issue.

I have to use the implementation in Project B but it gives me that error. I have imported the class and have also added the Project A in Build Path. Also the project is at top in dependency hierarchy. I am using RAD (similar to Eclipse).

If anyone could help me, that would be super helpful.

Comment: Did you import the wrong class? Because the compiler can find the class, it just does not declare, inherit or implement that method. Are you sure you pass a parameter of type `long`?

Comment: I imported the correct class. The class has other methods from that particular class which are being used fine but my newly added method is causing issues. It just doesn't recognize the newly added method.